# how to achive this with radio buttons without using ko.bindingHandlers

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button

view

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice"></select>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
```

viewModel

```
var viewModel = {
    choices: ["Nie", "Täglich", "Wöchentlich"],
    selectedChoice: ko.observable("Täglich")
};

viewModel.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   alert("the new value is " + newValue); 
});


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/vZC8A/1/

Comment: Your question is very unclear? What do you want to achieve? Do you want there radio buttons for "Nie", "Täglich", "Wöchentlich" instead of the dropdown and store the selected one in the `selectedChoice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go http://jsfiddle.net/vZC8A/3/, hope it helps, customize as needed

```
<div data-bind="foreach: choices">
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="choices"
           data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedChoice" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vZC8A/2/

I think you want something like above. The [checked](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) binding and using [virtual elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).

```
<!-- ko foreach: choices -->
<input type="radio" name="group1" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedChoice, value: $data" /> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```